# Call function after complete async loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For example we've following code:

```
var data = [obj, obj, obj];

function handler(k, v) {
  ...
  check(v, function() {});
}

function check(params, callback) {
  ...
  request(options, callback);
}

function request(opts, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    opts
    ...
    callback
  });
}

$.each(data, handler);
```

How can we wait for done `$.each` and call some function? For example, something look like:

```
$.when($.each(data, handler)).then(alert(1));
```

I can not find solution.

P.S. We can not know length of data.

P.S. this is not duplicate because code apologize using promises or something pretty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: call function after async each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591248/jquery-call-function-after-async-each)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the [`q`](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) library and start using promises for this problem. You can also include each callback in the previous one, creating your first [Pyramid of Doom](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the jqXHR objects and stack them up in an array with `$.map`:

```
var data = [obj, obj, obj];

function handler(v, i) {
  ...
  return check(v, function() {});
}

function check(params, callback) {
  ...
  return request(options, callback);
}

function request(opts, callback) {
  return $.ajax({
    ...
    opts
    ...
    callback
  });
}

$.when($.map(data, handler)).then(function(){

  });
```

Comment: Nice solution, but not working for me: then can't get results of new var after executing

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "then can't get results of new var". You want to reach the resolved values of each individual deferred object? They are part of the `arguments` object inside the `then` handler.

Comment: Oh, my bad, look: `function handler` have an array of all results, and when i use `$.then(function(){console.log(array of results)})` it's empty because was executed before end of loop

Comment: Well, sounds like it's part of the omitted code and another type of error (maybe your results aren't global). You shouldn't be dealing with your results this way, like I said before, you'd need to grab them from the arguments object inside the `then` handler.